# Speech recognition listener doesn't work in Galaxy SII

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am developing an Android application which always listen voice from user. It works when I run it on Sony X10i, but doesn't work in Samsung Galaxy SII.
Here is my code:

```
    SpeechRecognizer     speechRecognizer;
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getBaseContext());
    MyRecognitionListener speechListner=new MyRecognitionListener();
    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(speechListner);
    speechRecognizer.startListening(RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent(getApplicationContext()));
```

Here is my listener class:

```
class MyRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    }

    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onBufferReceived");
    }

    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onEndOfSpeech");
    }

    public void onError(int error) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onError");
    }

    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onEvent");
    }

    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onPartialResults");
    }

    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onReadyForSpeech");
    }


    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onResults");

    }

    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.d("leapkh", "onRmsChanged");
    }
}
```

In this case, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution.

Change the parameter of `speechRecognizer.startListening()` method to `intent` as below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());
    speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameters you are passing with the intent

```
{
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");

 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());

 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);

 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

    if (speech != null) {
            speech = null;

        }

        SpeechRecognizer speech SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);

        speech.startListening(intent);
```

}

Also Check which type of error you are getting 
 for nomatch,network and server error call startListening again

```
    public void startListening() {
    try {

        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) {
            if (speech != null) {
                speech.startListening(intent);

            } else {
                SimpleMethod();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```