# waking up the phone with voice command?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, wakeup

is there any way to wake up the android when it is on standby, by saying a specific voice command?
I found this post,[Speech recognition listener doesn't work in Galaxy SII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238396/speech-recognition-listener-doesnt-work-in-galaxy-sii)  but I guess this one is consuming so much battery .

I would highly appreciate any idea or recommendation on this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I believe anyhow you will end up consuming a lot of battery power if you need to listen to a microphone. You need to press button before or use something else to trigger recognition.

Comment: thanks @ArtemIce you are right. so the question is what will be the better way to invoke an action with the least interaction with the phone.?

Comment: What do you mean by least interaction? If you mean without physically touching the phone, a bluetooth device could do it (I know the headset I have wakes up the phone)

Comment: thanks @jay no I actually mean the minimum interaction between human and the phone. Because I am designing apps for older people, and requirement for that is to interact with the phone as little as possible :)

Comment: This is a pretty random idea, but have you seen those keyrings you can get in £1 (so I guess $1 stores too) where you clap/whistle and they bleep to help you find them? You could make a device that wires into the (micro) usb port of the phone, so the user could clap, it would send a pulse and wake up the phone. Something like that.

Comment: not sure what you are referring to? could you give me a link to one of those? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could, the CPU would not be able to go into Deep Sleep because the microphone would have to be listening/recording, and some processing would have to occur to see if a specific command has been said.

This would require the CPU to continually tick at (least) it's lowest frequency which, regardless of how well you write your code, will drain battery.

So no, there is no battery efficient solution I'm afraid (unless, somehow, you manage to implement this *under* Android, e.g. in hardware or something lower-level).